# Unable to integrate keycloak with angular Js 1.x -- seeking Guidence

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, authentication, keycloak

I am reaching out to seek your guidance on integrating Keycloak authentication into an Angualar JS 1.x application.

We have an existing application registered on Keycloak, and we have the necessary credentails, including the realm, URL, and client ID. Now we are looking to enhance the security of our application by incorporating token-based authentication with Keycloak.

If there are any best practives, recommended resources, tutorials, or code samples that you could share to guide us through this process, it would be immensely helpful for our development

I appreciate your time and expertise in advance and thank you for contributing to the strength of the Keycloak community. We look forward to benefiting from your insights.

Thanks